# Hyper-V VMMS won't start in Windows 8.1 pro

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, hyper-v

When I try to run an emulator in `Visual Studio` it tell's me my `Hyper-V` can't start, the strange thing is that it used to work some time ago.

[image: Error starting emulator]

What I already discovered is that my `Hyper-V` virtual machine management service won't start up.

[image: Error starting emulator]

When I try to start it from services it gives me following error:

> Windows could not start the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Mangement service on Local Computer. Error 0x80004003: Invalid pointer

The Hyper-V-VMMS log files give me this error id: `14096`

It also gives me this error in the logs with the id: `18602`

> The component registration information could not be read from the Msvm_VirtualSystemResourceComponent.Name="Microsoft|Shutdown Integration Component|V1.0" WMI object: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. is not a valid Win32 application. (0x800700C1). If this error persists, try re-installing the Hyper-V and dependent roles.

What I've tried so far:

- Stop hyper-V and start it again (with reboots)
- Check the BIOS for hyper-V settings
- Searched for my error online

Comment: I would remove hyper-v from the system.  Once the machine reboots you can add it back.  You can add and remove hyper-v in add/remove windows features.

Comment: I've done that multiple times but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: only other suggestion I have is to do a repair on windows 8.1 or upgrade to windows 10 if possible

Comment: upgrade to windows 10 solved the issue